# Chrome extension alert won't fire from the background.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

Tring to run a background script to fire an alert.
It's loaded successfully, but no alert.

manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Hello Extensions",
  "permissions": [
          "downloads","storage"
  ],
  "description" : "Base Level Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "hello.html",
    "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {"persistent": true, "scripts": ["background.js"]}
}
```

background.js:

```
alert("hello");
```

Comment: It's possible `alert` doesn't work there. It definitely doesn't work in Firefox. It's a bad debugging method anyway: forget it and use devtools for the background page.

Comment: It's only for chrome. Which tool I have to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @wOxxOm,

Found that there is an option to debug the background script.
In **chrome://extensions/** find your extention then "**Inspect views
background page**"

If I click this, the alert does show up (but not if I open a new tab or a new window).

*Note: if you try to use jquery in the script it should be specified 
before the 'background.js' in the manifest.*

Comment: By default I don't think alerts are shown, looking at the background page console is a good way to see if any errors are generated...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `chrome.notifications`:

**In background.js:**

```
chrome.notifications.create(
  "Example",
  {
    type: "basic",
    iconUrl: "32.png",
    title: 'Titel',
    message: 'Message'
  }
);
chrome.notifications.clear("Example");
```

The icon path is relative to your extension root.

**In manifest.js:**

```
"permissions": [
  "notifications"
]
```

Indeed, wOxxOm is right: **It's a bad way of debugging**. But sometimes a good idea, if an error is hunted in the background, which rarely occurs, but you want to be informed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

For me, debugging why the `chrome.notifications.create` wasn't working in background.js (after checking that no error messages were being generated in background' page console), this meant that notifications were globally turned off on the particular windows box I was developing on.  To double check click on notifications (show its tab, bottom right of screen) -> manage notifications -> "Get notifications from apps and other senders" make sure is toggled on.

When it is off it seems to show no error messages in javascript at all...sniff...